# Preview tool on Mac OS X 10.10 adds transparency during resize

Tags: macos, transparency, preview, alpha-transparency

The Preview tool on Mac OS X adds transparency during resize!

Steps to reproduce:

1. Save the following image. It doesn't contain transparent colors and color profiles.
   [image]
2. Open it in Finder by double click.
3. Resize it to 144 pixels using opened Preview tool.

You will get transparent image. You can check transparency on Photoshop. You will see the following result:

[image]

Why does this happen? Only some colors raise the issue.

Comment: it doesn't get transparent on my Mac OS X 10.10.1, Preview 8.0 (859)

Comment: I have Preview 8.0 (859) too. And I double checked - the issue presets. Did you check the result image on Photoshop? You can see background pattern as prove of the transparency.

Comment: I checked in GraphicConverter. The Alpha channel is completely black.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic and better asked at http://apple.stackexchange.com/ ; it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: cell, but please check it in Photoshop. Why the image is transparent on Photoshop?

Comment: Evert, any programmer needs correct icons for his apps.

Comment: @Altaveron Yes, ***but this question is still not about programming***. I've voted to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like Photoshop shows transparency on the file without it. So, it's Photoshop issue. As it work very wrong if you select "don't control color profiles" during file opening.